# How to change parent data from a child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

After doing some digging, it seems that from child to parent you should update data by emitting events (not by [v-model](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html)). This is my attempt of doing that (to no avail).

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld :count="count" @update:count="count= $event" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 10
    };
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <input
      type="number"
      min="0"
      :value="count"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      style="width:6em"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    count: Number
  }
};
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong? Ideally, I would like that changes in the input field of the child component would change the deposit field of the parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that doesn't work because you're missing  `emits: ['update:count']` option in child component, But I recommend to name the prop as `modelValue` in child component and use `v-model` directive in parent instead of `@update:count` event :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld v-model="count" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 10
    };
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

HelloWorld.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <input
      type="number"
      min="0"
      :value="count"
     @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      style="width:6em"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    modelValue: Number
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
};
</script>
```

This allows you to create a [custom input](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components)

Comment: This works, but the value that goes from child to parent ends up as a String instead of as a Number, any idea why? (initial values: count=10, after change/increment count="11")

Comment: try out `@input="$emit('update:modelValue', Number($event.target.value))"`

Comment: i'm not sure if `v-model.number="count"` works